# Generate sequence number that resets every year

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I would like to update inserted record (from weab application) with some sequence number that resets every year. It should have the form of 1/2019, 2/2019, 1/2020 etc.

The first solution I made up was to use trigger on insert action.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  GenerateActivityNumber
   ON  dbo.Activity
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    update Activity set Activity.ActivityNumber =  CONCAT(NEXT VALUE FOR ActivityCounter, '/', YEAR(GETDATE()))  WHERE Activity.id = (select Id from inserted)
END
```

Seems nice but I can't see any way to reset sequence other than using a job that runs every year. 
Second idea was much simple but it's not very safe (risk of duplicates) - counting records for current year and incrementing the value (still inside trigger)

```
select MAX(id)+1 from activity where  YEAR(CreatedDate) =  YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Do you have any idea how to improve solutions shown above? Or are there any other better solutions?

Comment: Can you schedule a job to reset the sequence at new year?

Comment: @the_lotus I would rather avoid this scenario

Comment: Do you really need to start at 1 each year? Do you really need the year to be part of the ID? Can't it just be an auto-incremental value that doesn't have any type of meaning? You can keep the created date in another column.

Comment: @EzLo Yes, it has to start from 1 every year.

Comment: @drv Please check out this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159629/reset-a-sequence-every-year